# If category is in parent category?

Tags: categories, functions

I have function that check what is main top category of post. So i have category tree like this

```
Foo
-bar
--foobar
cat2
```

and if post is in foobar, my function  post_is_in_descendant_category shows me "foo" and i can style that post with style-foo.css. What i want now is to make this same possible for styling category page "foobar". Wordpress functions in_category works only for posts.

So, my code `if ( in_category( 'foo' ) ||  post_is_in_descendant_category( get_term_by( 'name', 'foo', 'category' )) || is_category('56') )` doesn't work for subcategories.

Comment: So i want something like this: If currently displayed category is child category of "foo" include "foo.css" elseif, is child of "cat2" include cat2.css, else include style.css (default style for categories). 
My current code for this is http://pastebin.com/Cvh6R2ms and works only for posts, not categories

Comment: Could you please explain _styling category page "foobar"_ better? Do you mean archive of _foobar_ category? Something else?

Comment: Yes Rarst, i want to change stylings of all posts, categories and category "foo" with my foo.css style. Also, i want to style all posts, categories and posts in category "cat2" and so on. Check my previous comment with pastebin link, there is some code i shared there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand right your "post_is_in_descendant_category" function checks if a post is descendant of a category and you want to check if a category is descentand. If so the add this function to your functions.php

```
function is_desc_cat($cats, $_post = null) {
  foreach ((array)$cats as $cat) {
    if (in_category($cat, $_post)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      if (!is_int($cat)) $cat = get_cat_ID($cat);
      $descendants = get_term_children($cat, 'category');
      if ($descendants && in_category($descendants, $_post)) return true;
    }
  }

return false;
}
```

and use it  like this:

```
if (is_desc_cat("foo")) {
  // use foo.css
} else {
  // use default.css
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, this one works, but i have some bugs with code. http://pastebin.com/u501HeC2

Comment: Fixed, all works great

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$cat_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
$parents = explode( '/', get_category_parents( $cat_id, false ) );

if( in_array( 'foo', $parents ) ) {

}
elseif( in_array( 'cat2', $parents ) ) {

}
else {


}
```